# Python: Handle different datetime format dynamically

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I have a different DateTime format coming in for Day, Week, Month, and Quarter. I would like to know if there is a way to handle it or I have to maintain a map of all possible DateTime formats.

```
       Input Format     || Output Format
Day:     Oct 24         —>  2021-10-24
Week:    Week of Oct 18 —>  2021-10-18
Month:   Oct ’21        —>  2021-10-01
Quarter: 2021 Q3        —>  2021-07-01
```

I know the `parser.parse` function from `dateutil` library. Using that I don't need to know what format of datetime string is, and it'll convert the string into datetime object. But that doesn't work here.

So, if anyone knows any in-built function which I can use please let me know.

Comment: I don't think there's a "built-in function" for this. On the other hand, if you can limit the formats you expect, I don't think it's too difficult to write a custom parser yourself. E.g. for given example, the "special cases" are string containing a `’` which signals a year and `Q` which signals a quarter.

Comment: Hi @MrFuppes  that's exactly what I did. Made my own custom parser, but I might come across a different kind of DateTime format which I don't know of beforehand. That's why I was asking if there is a built-in function that handles the format on the fly.

Comment: "*on the fly*" would mean that the parser needs to generalize in some way, so still, I think a custom parser might be the better option. If you encounter errors, you'll have to adjust it, but with proper testing, you'll know it won't give e.g. "false positives".